# What format is the database dump from the Georeferenzierung project?

Tags: database, gis, wikipedia

I am searching for a way to access the data contained in a dump file of Wikipedia's georeferencing project offered [on this site](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:WikiProjekt_Georeferenzierung/Hauptseite/Wikipedia-World/en) at the bottom of the righthand box. [download link](https://tools.wmflabs.org/wp-world/dumps/new_red0.gz)

After unpacking the .gz archive, a 4.7GB file named `new_red0` remains **without any file extension**.

Can anyone help me open this file using Windows 10?

Comment: It is a PostGIS database dump. You need a PostgreSQL database with PostGIS support, then you can restore the dump to the database.

Comment: @warmoverflow Thanks for your comment. PostgreSQL+PostGis works. I'd accept it as an answer.